# Using glossaries with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, indexing, glossaries, landscape

I hope someone can help with this. I am trying to generate a document with a glossary. I am using TexnicCenter. It appears to work when there is no bibtex file but not when there is and then not even when the bibtex file is then removed. I have amended the postprocessor to include makeglossaries. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\linespread{1.6}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{images/}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape} % or {pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries} \include{litrev.gls}
\makeglossaries
\makeindex
\usepackage{makeidx}
\begin{document}
\include{litrev.glo}
\gls{hrt}
\gls{usa}
\Section{Introduction:}

\gls{usa}


\printindex
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

I then run this through latex and then run makeglossaries litrev.

At this point I get these errors in my .glg file:

*** Unable to execute: 'xindy  -L english  -I xindy -M "litrev" -t "litrev.glg" -o "litrev.gls" "litrev.glo"' ***

Status report:

Opening logfile "litrev.glg" ERROR: Opening logfile "litrev.glg" failed!

I hope this is all relevant information. Any help would be Greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Hi, the information is a bit sparse. Bibtex does not seem to be your problem but the xindy call. Is there any more information as to why it fails?

Comment: Hi Martin H, This works completely when I move the file to another folder now but I cannot get it to work in the original folder. The only additional information that I have is when I ran makeglossaries I got the error "call to xindy failed". I have got it to work now though. Thank you!

Comment: You're not suppose to explicitly include the `.glo` and `.gls` files (also it's not a good idea to use `\include` in the preamble, use `\input` instead). Where have you defined your glossary entries? Can you trim your MWE down a bit, removing all the packages that aren't relevant to the problem.

Comment: Hi Nicola, Thanks for that. I put all of the packages in the MWE because I wasn't sure what might or might not be affecting it. My glossary entries are stored in the .gls file. Thank you for the advice on input. I will change that. It is working as is but only in one folder and I'm just a bit concerned that it could fall over easily. Janet

Comment: You don't mean you've defined your entries in the `.gls` file, do you? That file gets overwritten by `xindy` (or `makeindex`). Also the `.glo` file gets overwritten by `glossaries` every time you build your document. If you want to define entries in a separate file, put them in a file with the extension `.tex`. (BTW put an `@` in front of my name if you want me to be notified when you make a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Neither the `.glo` nor the `.gls` files should be explicitly input into a document. The `.glo` file is opened for output during the document build and the `glossaries` package writes information to it that is then used by the indexing application. The `.glo` file contains indexing syntax, not LaTeX syntax. The `.gls` file is implicitly loaded by `\printglossary` (or `\printglossaries`). Although the `.gls` file contains LaTeX commands to print the glossary, there is additional information that has to be set up before the file is loaded, which is what `\printglossary` does, so the `.gls` file shouldn't be simply inputted into the document.

If you want to define entries in a separate file to your main document, give the file the standard `.tex` extension. For example, create a file called, say, `litrev.tex` that contains your `\newglossaryentry` commands:

```
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={a sample entry
with a citation~\cite{article-minimal}}}
```

In your document, this file is loaded via `\loadglsentries`. For example:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% load entry definitions from file:
\loadglsentries{litrev}

\begin{document}

Use an entry: \gls{sample}.

\printglossary

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

The `%arara:` directives aren't required, but they show you the order of the document build.

(Tip: if you don't know whether a package should be included into a MWE, try removing it and see if there is any change to the problem. If there isn't, the package isn't needed for the example.)

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you. This works perfectly. Thanks. Janet.